# Select Control in XSLT

Tags: asp.net, .net, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm using select control in XSLT. In aspx page, Onchnage of dropdown value, I need to get the selected dropdown value. I'm able to fire the dropdown cange event but unable to get which option is selected...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XSLT in ASP, then you are generating HTML. Do you know what HTML you want to generate? If not, you have an HTML problem and not an XSLT (or ASP) problem. If you do know what HTML you want to generate, then tell us, and we can help you generate it.

On the other hand, if you want to handle user interaction within XSLT itself, then consider running interactive XSLT client side, using Saxon-CE (or the new Frameless processor, which I haven't tried).

Comment: I'm aware of HTML that is being generated from my XSLT. I'm using something similar to below code which is firing on change of dropdown value(the dropdown is placed in XSLT). I'm trying to get selected value through $(this). could you pls help in this lin e?? $(document).on('change', '.DropDown', function () {
           // debugger;
$(this).get(0).id 
        });

Comment: So you're generating HTML which doesn't do what you want? That's not an XSLT problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response, could you please suggest me how can I acheive a dropdown in XSLT without using Saxon-CE

Comment: Tell us what HTML you want to generate, and we can tell you how to generate it from XSLT.

Comment: Dropdown with certains values <select id="testDropDown" onselectedindexchanged="javacsript:return ShowSelectedValue();"> <option value="A">A</option><option value="B">B</option></select> in xslt .. On change ofthis value, I need that value to be displayed in Javascript

Comment: I still think you're asking us for help with the HTML, not with the XSLT. But you don't seem to have got it clear in your head that these are completely separate from each other.